# Use string which is the same as the database-column-name to recognize which property to use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

(Just using the {{ }} to tell which data is variable)

This gets the data from the database and puts it into a property. The `Table_Column` and `PropertyName` are usually not the same.

```
[Column(Name = "{{Table_Column}}")]
public string {{PropertyName}} { get; set; }
```

In this class the data (which is contained by properties in the location of `{{PropertyName}}`)is connected to the `docElement`. `docElement` contains the name of the element and the name of the `Table_Column`.

```
var documentElements = GetAllElements();

foreach (DocumentElement docElement in documentElements)
{
    ConnectData<Document>(docElement.ElementName, (doc) => doc.{{PropertyName}});
}
```

I want to connect data to my Elements using my function `ConnectData`, which requires me to give an `ElementName` and the data I want to connect to the Element. The `documentElements`, which I loop through with a foreach, all have an `ElementName` and `ElementType`. That `ElementType` is the same as `{{Table_Column}}` of the database. With that I want to find which property I need to call to get the right data.

Thanks in advance!
Questions? Please leave a comment.

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: Look into reflection. It's the only way to achieve this. However, be mindful that using reflection slows your application *considerably*, so it should only be used sparingly, if at all.